# Dismounting a disk prior to formatting

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, boot

Windows XP sp3. Disk 0 = E:, Disk 1 = C:, boots from Disk1 (can switch in BIOS between boot disks). Installed Windows 7 on E: after Windows XP on C:. Want to format E: (wipe it clean) and install XP on it, transfer programs from C:, and eventually wipe C: and make it a pure data disk, and later install Windows 7 and Linux on E:.

Problem: Format warns that I must dismount E: before formatting, because it is in use. Is "in use" solely due to the way the boot sequence on C: is structured? There is nothing else using the disk when booted into XP on C:. NOTE: Default boot is into Windows 7 on E:, with "Prior operating systems" on C: the next choice.

Will wiping disk E: disable the boot sequence on C:? I don't think so, but I want to be sure. Also, why the heck doesn't Microsoft give us tools for un-installing Windows?

Comment: Microsoft does give us tools to uninstall Windows: It's called "Format".

Comment: We are not talking partitions correct? E: is a separate hd? If your worried about boot sequence then disconnect the hd that is E: and boot up

Comment: @Logman WHAT???  E: can only be a partition. You only format partitions. Sometimes a partition might occupy/be the size of, a whole drive.

Comment: @barlop uhmm, when I go to Disk Mgmt I see Disk 0 | Disk 1 | Disk 2 etc... Ed Dewan stats Disk 0 = E & Disk 1 = C ...... which should mean he has multiple DISKs... there is no mention of "partitions", just "disks". I meant different parition on a different hard disk btw

Comment: I'm not disputing that he has multiple disks. For the record, disk management -does not- mislead one into confusing this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb457110.f12zs01_big(l=en-us).jpg

Answer (score 0):

just say yes let it "dismount" so windows can format it, as that's what you want. But i'd  say label it first(carefully). so it's then clearer -to you- what you are formatting.

you'd have an issue booting if you formatted the active/bootable partition, but even that is easy to fix. Load the recovery console, do the command   bootcfg /rebuild.  it finds all win xp intallaions, makes a menu of them, menu stored in boot.ini on the bootable partition, with a few other things. You can change which partition is bootable eg with gparted live.

Changing the active partition from the xp recovery console (even in diskpart) may not be possible. 'cos its diskpart is reduced. Not as good as the one in the actual OS proper.

See this from wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskpart 
"On the Recovery Console, which is included in all Windows 2000, Windows XP and Windows Server 2003, there is a diskpart command which is significantly different from the one included in the actual operating system. It only provides functionality for adding and deleting partitions, but not for setting an active partition.[3] The utility is also provided in the Windows Recovery Environment, the successor of the original Recovery Console."

It's not really necessary to wonder why windows is asking you to dismount it. You think it's not in use.  So what. It doesn't matter. Maybe Windows is storing System Volume Information like System Restore stuff on it.

You could open a cmd prompt run diskpart and find out which partition is the bootable one(windows calls that, "active").

> D:\Documents and Settings\User>diskpart
>
> Microsoft DiskPart version 5.1.3565
>
> Copyright (C) 1999-2003 Microsoft Corporation. On computer: DELL-DT1
>
> DISKPART> select disk
>
> There is no disk selected.
>
> DISKPART> list disk
>
> Disk ###  Status      Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt   -------- 
>   ----------  -------  -------  ---  ---   Disk 0    Online       233 GB    43 GB
>
> DISKPART> select disk 0
>
> Disk 0 is now the selected disk.
>
> DISKPART> list partition
>
> Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset   ------------- 
>   ----------------  -------  -------   Partition 1    Primary              8 GB  1024 KB   Partition 2    Primary           7999 MB     8 GB
>   Partition 3    Extended           192 GB    16 GB   Partition 4
>   Logical             42 GB    16 GB   Partition 5    Logical
>   32 GB    76 GB   Partition 6    Logical            100 GB   109 GB
>
> DISKPART> detail part
>
> There is no partition selected. Please select a partition and try
>   again.
>
> DISKPART> select partition
>
> There is no partition selected.
>
> DISKPART> select partition 1
>
> Partition 1 is now the selected partition.
>
> DISKPART> help
>
> Microsoft DiskPart version 5.1.3565
>
> .. {Googled how to get diskpart to show active partition!}
>
> DISKPART> detail
>
> Microsoft DiskPart version 5.1.3565
>
> DISK        - Print a list of volumes on the disk. PARTITION   - Shows
>   details about the current partition. VOLUME      - Print a list of
>   disks that contribute to the volume.
>
> DISKPART> detail partition
>
> Partition 1 Type  : 0B Hidden: No Active: Yes
>
> Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status
>   Info   ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------
>
> ---
>
> - Volume 1     C   DOS          FAT32  Partition      8 GB  Healthy    System
>
> DISKPART> detail partition 2
>
> The arguments you specified for this command are not valid.
>
> DISKPART> select partition 2
>
> Partition 2 is now the selected partition.
>
> DISKPART> detail partition 2
>
> The arguments you specified for this command are not valid.
>
> DISKPART> detail partition
>
> Partition 2 Type  : 0B Hidden: No Active: No
>
> Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status
>   Info   ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------
>
> ---
>
> - Volume 2     H   Winsetup     FAT32  Partition   7999 MB  Healthy
>
> DISKPART>

It is possible for your active partition to not be C. As my active partition is the first on the disk, and while this windows calls itself D, there's another partition from an old installation, which calls itself C, and that partition is not active.

The asterisk diskpart uses just marks the selected partition, not the active one.

Ignore the bullet points, that's just superuser converting * to asterisks.

If you manage to format your active partition, then you wouldn't be able to boot, but it's easily fixable.

also you can open a cmd prompt and do  dir /a e:\boot.ini   If it doesn't have that, it's not the active partition. If it does, then it could potentially be, and has been at one time.    boot.ini stores the booting menu that lists your windows installations. If that is gone then you'll have trouble booting, but as mentioned in comment, even that's easy to fix just load the recovery console e.g. from cd.. and run bootcfg /rebuild. there are some other commands you can try.  fixboot and fixmbr are the relevant others people try to fix problems booting.

Also, if you have more than one hard disk ten each might have an active partition, but the BIOS decides which hard disk is booted from. Then after that, whichever partition on that disk is active, is booted.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you barlop, you have given me a lot to chew on. To Logman, yes, drive E: is a separate disk, and its own partition (un-partitioned), if this is the right terminology. I may have a few more comments to make on this subject, but my wife wants me to clean up her gardening tools, since the weather is nice for the first time in several days, so I will go away for a little while.